# set::sort CakePHP array

Tags: cakephp-2, array-multidimensional, classificação

Preciso ordenar um array em cakephp de acordo com a ordem passada por parâmetro.

O código que faz a ordenação seria este:

```
 //Realizar a ordenação de acordo com o que receber do formulário no ajax

    if ($this->request->data['Advertencia']['campo_ordem'] == 'Funcionario.quantidade|asc') {
        $retornoFinal = Set::sort($retornoFinal, '{n}.{s}.Funcionario.quantidade', 'asc');
    }else if($this->request->data['Advertencia']['campo_ordem'] == 'Funcionario.quantidade|desc'){
        $retornoFinal = Set::sort($retornoFinal, '{n}.{s}.Funcionario.quantidade', 'desc');
    }else if($this->request->data['Advertencia']['campo_ordem'] == 'Funcionario.matricula|asc'){
        $retornoFinal = Set::sort($retornoFinal, '{n}.{s}.Funcionario.matricula', 'asc');
    }else if($this->request->data['Advertencia']['campo_ordem'] == 'Funcionario.matricula|desc'){
        $retornoFinal = Set::sort($retornoFinal, '{n}.{s}.Funcionario.matricula', 'desc');
    }else if($this->request->data['Advertencia']['campo_ordem'] == 'Funcionario.nome|desc'){
        $retornoFinal = Set::sort($retornoFinal, '{n}.{s}.Funcionario.nome', 'desc');
    }else{
        $retornoFinal = Set::sort($retornoFinal, '{n}.{s}.Funcionario.nome', 'asc');
    }
```

O array inicialmente está neste formato:

```
Array
(
[5307] => Array
    (
        [A] => Array
            (
                [Funcionario] => Array
                    (
                        [quantidade] => 2
                        [matricula] => 5307
                        [nome] => DIOMAR 
                        [tipo_punicao] => A
                    )

            )

        [CA] => Array
            (
                [Funcionario] => Array
                    (
                        [quantidade] => 4
                        [matricula] => 5307
                        [nome] => DIOMAR 
                        [tipo_punicao] => CA
                    )

            )

        [RC] => Array
            (
                [Funcionario] => Array
                    (
                        [quantidade] => 4
                        [matricula] => 5307
                        [nome] => DIOMAR 
                        [tipo_punicao] => RC
                    )

            )

        [SR] => Array
            (
                [Funcionario] => Array
                    (
                        [quantidade] => 2
                        [matricula] => 5307
                        [nome] => 
                        [tipo_punicao] => SR
                    )

            )

    )

[5401] => Array
    (
        [A] => Array
            (
                [Funcionario] => Array
                    (
                        [quantidade] => 2
                        [matricula] => 5401
                        [nome] => VALDOMIRO 
                        [tipo_punicao] => A
                    )

            )

        [CA] => Array
            (
                [Funcionario] => Array
                    (
                        [quantidade] => 1
                        [matricula] => 5401
                        [nome] => VALDOMIRO 
                        [tipo_punicao] => CA
                    )

            )

        [RC] => Array
            (
                [Funcionario] => Array
                    (
                        [quantidade] => 2
                        [matricula] => 5401
                        [nome] => VALDOMIRO 
                        [tipo_punicao] => RC
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Quando entra nos IFs que ordenam por 'Nome' ou 'Matricula' funciona corretamente, porém pela 'QUANTIDADE' não funciona e esta é a mais importante. É possível fazer de outra forma ou arrumar?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho reputação suficiente para comentar sua pergunta, logo, escreverei aqui. Essa ordenação que você quer fazer é apenas visual (para o usuário) ou tem que ser também ordenada no array? Se for somente visual utilize via JavaScript ;)

Comment: Preciso que ordene no array, realmente. Entendo que poderia ser feito por java script, porém neste caso não se aplica.

Comment: Certo, então você pode fazer um simples `$search = $this->NomeModel->find('all' array('order' => $param))` e retornar `$search` onde `$param` é semelhante à `nome DESC`

Comment: Porém da forma que citei, poderá ficar muito lenta caso haja muitos dados... Mas é algo que funciona.. Vi que existe uma função no Cake para ordenar o array sem precisar fazer múltiplas requisições.. Vou dar uma olhada e testar e qualquer coisa mando aqui..

Comment: É um pouco mais complicado que isto o que estou fazendo. Este array que passei contém valores, como QUANTIDADE, que não vem do Model. Foi calculado e inserido no array e preciso sortear este valor por Quantidade Decrescente e Crescente. O estranho é que da forma como está, funciona corretamente para 'Nome', 'Matricula', mas não para quantidade.

Comment: Já tentou remover o `{s}` da frente da `Quantidade`?

Comment: Sim, porém não funciona também. Vou postar aqui em baixo outra forma que poderia me ajudar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23584/discussion-between-julyano-felipe-and-rodrigo-segatto).

Comment: Talvez se ficasse desta forma poderia me ajudar: ideone.com/MkxRQX